# SQL queries on every page load codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

On all page loads, I have these queries running on my MYSQL server :

```
      155 Query SET SESSION sql_mode =
                REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                @@sql_mode,
                "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,", ""),
                ",STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,", ""),
                ",STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", ""),
                "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", "")
      155 Query SET NAMES utf8
      155 Quit
```

How can I prevent these requests from running? I tried to deactivate "char_set" and "dbcollat" in config/database.php but this has no effect

Comment: How?, How you come to know that these queries are running on your mysql? Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: I activated the logs with my wampserver, I have a file named "general-query.log" which lists all the MYSQL queries executed

Comment: Thanks man, I will search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter is turning MySQL's strict sql mode off. In the `database.php` set the `strickton` parameter to `true` to enable strict mode.

However, codeigniter wants to make sure that the settings configured for every connection. If you want to take care of these settings in the MySQL config files, then you need to remove (well, comment out) these options from the  `database.php`.

Comment: I tried your solution, it's better but I always have two requests which run even if I comment out options in config / database.php

Comment: Then you need to find in your code where these settings are called. Perhaps, you are adding them manually or are configured in MySQL on a client level. If the 2 statements that run at every connection are related to character sets (e.g. `set names`), then I would not really worry about them - unless incorrect character set is configured.

Comment: Yes the requests are related to the character sets, I will finally leave them in this case. Thank you for your help !